# Is it possible to generate sine tones in Processing.JS?

Tags: javascript, processing, processing.js

I am an amateur musician and I teach music basics to school children who have little to no prior music education.

I've coded [a small app in Processing.JS](https://ohnoitsalobo.github.io/noteCircle/index.html) which shows the 12 musical notes of the Western scale (A, A#, B, C, C#, D, D#, E, F, F#, G, G#) in a circle, and highlights the relationships between them from which musical scales/intervals are constructed.

I want to be able to touch a particular note name and generate the sine tone associated with that note (the very obvious one being A = ..., 220Hz, 440Hz, 880Hz, ...)

So to break it down, in Processing.JS, is it possible to generate a sine tone of a desired frequency upon detection of a mouse event? If someone can help me work that out, I can figure out the rest.

To be clear: I'm not too good at Javascript, and I'm moderate at Processing, at best. I know Javascript can do stuff like this but I don't know how to integrate the two languages in this webapp.

Comment: I guess you could use the Web Audio API ... Or something like Tone.js

Comment: @EJTH could you tell me how? I don't know how to integrate Javascript and Processing.JS as I've not had much experience with Javascript.

Comment: Generally you use <script> tags to include dependencies such as tone.js. Read the reference for tone.js on how to use it.

Comment: @Boloar Have a look at [this article](http://processingjs.org/articles/jsQuickStart.html) on how to integrate ProcessingJS with JavaScript to use other sound libraries. Alternatively you can port your Processing syntax to P5.js (very similar) and use it's [p5.sound](https://p5js.org/reference/#/libraries/p5.sound) library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you've hinted at, you're going to have to do this in JavaScript. George's comment is spot-on: you should start by reading through [this page](http://processingjs.org/articles/jsQuickStart.html).

But basically, the thing to keep in mind is that Processing.js gets converted into JavaScript, so you can call JavaScript code directly from Processing.js.

I'd start by googling something like "JavaScript sine tone" for a ton of results. [Tone.js](https://tonejs.github.io/) seems to be a library that does what you want, but I'm sure there are many others.

To use the Tone.js library, you need to first import it in your HTML, exactly how you're already importing the Processing.js library:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tone/13.3.10/Tone.js"></script>
```

Then you can use Tone.js in your Processing.js code:

```
var synth ;

void setup(){
  //create a synth and connect it to the master output (your speakers)
  synth = new Tone.Synth().toMaster();
}

void mousePressed(){
  //play a middle 'C' for the duration of an 8th note
  synth.triggerAttackRelease('C4', '8n')
}

void draw(){}
```

Note that Processing.js leaves JavaScript code alone when it does the conversion, so your final output is just a bunch of JavaScript code. That's why you can mix JavaScript code and Processing.js code like this.

But also like George said, you should probably consider switching over to P5.js, because Processing.js isn't maintained anymore.

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/processing-js) is a tutorial on Processing.js, and [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/p5js) are some tutorials on P5.js.